# I want moving particles

Tags: particles

[image: particles stay in T pose]Hello I want to make particles move with mesh then animation is playing like in hair system hair moves with mesh. So is it possible to move particles same way?

Comment: pls explain in detail (maybe be sketches, pictures, movies(links)) so that is clear what you want. One liner question often end up, that someone writes an answer and then the one, who wrote the question answer: oh now, but i wanted it that way....so pls don't let others waste their time just because you are too lazy to write a good detailed question. thx. and pls consider: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If you set the *Physics* of your particle system to *None*, the particles will follow the object just like Hairs.

(Of course, they won't have any physic, so I'm not sure that what you want)

Comment: Okey I set physics to type none but still particles stay in human shape T pose but I want them to move with human jump animation do You have other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As thibsert wrote, physics to None is right, but also make sure in the modifiers tab, that the particle system is below (after) the armature.